# GridView - Search. Error converting data type nvarchar to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My GridView was fine, but then I added a search. I'm having issues with it.

I get the error, but I thought all of my variables had the correct data type:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SQL Server is automagically converting int to string for your like, but I'm not sure if that's what you were really after. You declared this as int, but use it as a string. @DistrictId int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use appropriate parameter types, for example
    `<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="75" Name="EventId" Type="Int32" />`

Comment: Okay thanks, I fixed those few up to say Int32. Now I get the following error: `Input string was not in a correct format.` ... I don't know which one is throwing this error though.

Comment: %% is not numeric  =)

Comment: Ah! There we go. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you undo your edit, other people will then be able to see what was your error and how you solved it, helping them to solve their issues too ;)